# Why is undo/redo not working!

Tags: shortcut

I accidentally pressed some unknown key combination, and now I can't use Undo nor Redo in Blender

Comment: Basically, SHIFT + ALT toggles between being able to undo/redo and... NOT being able to undo/redo. That's all.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Pressing Shift + Alt when? As far as I am aware there is no way to disable undo/redo.

Comment: If you are using English Software (Blender) but an Azerty keyboard, accidentally hitting Shift + Alt keys toggles the keyboard to the Querty setup. This effectively "disables" the the Undo/Redo shortcuts. But of course they still work but now you need to use Ctrl + W to Undo instead of the usuall Crtl + Z. Or  use Shft + Alt to toggle back to your usuall keyboard setup.

Comment: @3fingeredfrog That is indeed curious and useful information, unfortunately the way the question and answer are worded it is impossible to understand what you explained. Could you please edit them so they read more like your comment.

Comment: @Duarte Thanks for making my comment a little more understandable :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using English Software (Blender) under Windows 
based Operating Systems but with an AZERTY keyboard, accidentally hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> keys toggles keyboard layouts, as [explained here](https://superuser.com/questions/66561/how-to-avoid-keyboard-layout-automatically-changing-on-windows).

This apparently "disables" the Undo/Redo operators, when in fact what happens is it changes the keyboard shortcuts

Ofcourse they still work, but now you need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to Undo instead of the usuall <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, or use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> to toggle back to your usual keyboard layout.

You can also disable the shortcut in the *Regional Options* of the control panel if you [follow the steps described here](https://superuser.com/questions/109066/how-to-disable-ctrlshift-keyboard-layout-switch-for-the-same-input-language-i)

Credit goes to [3fingeredfrog](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/31761/3fingeredfrog) for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but in my case wasn't by an key combination.

If other answers didn't solve problem go to the Blender *Users Preferences >  Edit > Activate Global Undo* (optionally add more steps if you want).

Answer (score 1):

For Mac, it is solved by hitting <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>Option</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⌥ Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> *> Preference > System >* *Memory and limits > Global undo*