# F12 doesn't render but opens object Parenting menu

Tags: rendering

Firstly, I am completely new in Blender. I am trying to follow a tutorial and try to render my first sculpture from Camera's view using **F12** key. Instead of rendering it just opens **Set Parent To** menu.

[image]
[screenshot of my current workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikXTL.png)

Comment: Make sure you are using the default keymap

Comment: I haven't changed any user interface. My keymap is set to Blender as default

Comment: Are you using an [AZERTY](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78085/why-is-undo-redo-not-working/) keyboard?

Comment: You were right, I did use azerty keyboard. I have disabled it now and use just English (United States) layout. But Blender still doesn't render when I press f12 and opens parenting menu. I am looking for other shortcuts that don't work. At this moment I haven't found any.

Comment: What OS are you running? Is there some way you can check to see if your F12 key is really being interpreted as F12? (such as xev in an X server)

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Your can render by using button RENDER here. And try to press Ctrl+P(it is supposed to be set for parenting objects)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did try pressing Ctrl+P it opened the same parenting menu like f12. I still wonder why the shortcut is not working tho