# Y and Z Keys are switched in 3D View

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, shortcut

I use both, a German and a UK keyboard layout. When I use the German layout the Y and Z Keys appear swapped in the 3D View and behave like in the UK layout. Inside text entry fields however the layouts behave as expected.

I use 2.78c on Ubuntu 17.10

Is this a bug, or a feature to ensure shortcut consistency? I find it quite confusing, that I have to mentally swap the Y and Z axes with the German layout.

Comment: Sounds like either a bug, an overlook, or an imcompatibility. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78085/why-is-undo-redo-not-working

Comment: The Shift + Alt thing should be only on windows.
Well, it could be an issue with wayland...

Comment: I too have this problem, since the blender 2.8 beta release. Have you found any solutions jet?

Comment: I started experiencing Z and Y axes swapped when moving vertices. The weird thing is that when I press G, Y, the green Y axis appears, positioned like a Z axis. Anyone can help? :(

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem! originally I thought it had something to do with me pressing Ctrl+I or something like that, but I later realized I had changed the keyboard from English to German. Once I switched it back everything was fine again.