# control Z and Command Z arent working

Tags: shortcut, osx

I just downlodet BLENDER and immediatly started watching tutorials. but then I nóticed that I cant undo my steps.command-and control Z are not doing anything.
this is bad especially for me as a beginner.
what can I do. I allready went into the prefences and toggled Global Undo but that didnot change my situation.

p.s.
I have mac and currently version 2.79 of blender

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78085/why-is-undo-redo-not-working

Comment: Does it work if you use the "Undo" button ? (in Toolshelf / Tools / History). If it works, right click this button, select "Change Shortcut", and choose any shortcut you want.