# Redo shortcut not working

Tags: shortcut

I'm using version 2.79 and can't redo with <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. My redo shortcut is <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and it is enabled in the Input tab in the User Preferences window. I can undo with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. I can redo with Tool Shelf -> Tools -> History -> Redo. Why is my shortcut not working?

Comment: The first sentence was cut off. It said "Hi I'm using Blender 2.79".

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78085/why-is-undo-redo-not-working/78116#78116

Comment: Hi. If you need to edit your post you can use the [edit] link under the question, but worth noting https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts and https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/466/editing-questions-to-remove-thank-you-etc

Answer (score 0):

This is very frustrating issue.

To solve it just use right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button on keyboard.

For whatever reason when you want to redo left one doesn't react but otherwise it works fine when you undo or do anything else, I don't understand what is the actual problem but this solution works it still beats going to Edit>redo every time.