# Some of the Blender shortcuts don't work

Tags: shortcut

After formatting, I reinstalled Blender. I reset the shortcut keys as they were originally used, but some shortcut keys do not work.
It doesn't work even though there are no overlapping shortcuts.
If change the shortcut key to something else, it will be applied, but the shortcut in the image above is convenient for me, so I want to keep using it.[image]

Comment: I've had a problem where a screenshotter program was interfering with Blender shortcuts, overriding them. Maybe you have a program running that hijacked those shortcuts.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78085/why-is-undo-redo-not-working

Comment: The currently installed screenshot program is only the Windows default capture tool..u_u