The '2' key for selecting edge does not work for the French keyboard
So I'm using the latest Blender version (4.3) on a Linux operating system (Ubuntu) and here's the problem, I got a french keyboard (AZERTY) and when I press 1 and 3 in Edit Mode it selects respectively vertices and faces but when I press 2 it does nothing, I checked the settings and here is a screenshot

I tried to remove the bind and re-assign the edge mode back to '2' selection bind and I get this error:

whereas when I try to rebind to '1', '3', '4' and '5' it works just fine

What do you see if you expand that setting with the little down arrow to the left of the checkbox? If it's exactly the same as the Vertex and Face entries but the Type: is 'Edge' I'd consider reporting it as a bug via the Help > Report a Bug menu.

@JohnEason Yes the type is 'Edge'. Ok alright I will report it. Thanks.

Does this answer your question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78085/why-is-undo-redo-not-working/78116#78116

I forgot to mention that I use Linux sorry, thanks for the help anyways
